# Get IP of user in NATed virtual server

Tags: c#, asp.net, virtualbox, nat

I have Windows Server in VirtualBox and NATed port 80 for that.
Request.UserHostAddress returns local IP of virtual network.
How should i get IP of user?

Comment: Why? That's kinda impossible anyway.

Comment: @fejesjoco I don't know. My server is Debian and i installed Windows Server 2012 in Virtual Box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you've got is that you can't see beyond NATing. NAT stands for `Network Address Translation` so in this instance, you're seeing the public IP address of the NAT device, not the client. That's just the way it works. It's possible for the client to send its local IP address but you'd need to have something on the client to do that.

A different option is to switch from NAT to Bridged networking. Bridged means that the virtual network the VM is on is joined side-by-side with the physical network the host is on. This means they'll have IP addresses which are on the same subnet and are routable from anything else on the same network. Bridges act like switches/hubs, NATs act like routers.

As long as your server / client don't have any NAT devices between them, the IPs should be readily visible using the standard mechanisms (eg `context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]`, `Request.UserHostAddress`, etc)

Comment: You said for test purposes... Is there any problem for doing that in production server? I use IIS, MailEnable, FTP ,... in VPS @Basic

Comment: Not at all... The only reason I said "for test purposes" was for you to try it and prove that it worked. I assumed you'd gone NAT for a reason as opposed to an arbitrary decision. If not, then bridged is absolutely the way you want to go. We have many production servers configured this way. I'll edit

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to get the user's public IP address?
Easiest approach is to simply create a PHP script to echo the remote address, or use an existing API that does so.

PHP:

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
?>
```

C#:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
    var response = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("URL"));
    IPAddress ip;

    if (IPAddress.TryParse(response, out ip)) {
        //Success
    }
}
```

Comment: Your two pieces of code don't do the same thing. What does the C# piece even do?

Comment: They're not supposed to do the same thing; the C# code uses an HttpClient to read a string (which is the IP address as echo'd by the PHP snippet). A very reliable way to get the external IP address.

Comment: That information should have been in your answer, but in any rate, the OP is not looking for the public IP address. The OP thought he could get the "real" IP address of the client, across the NAT.